# Is it 'disingenuousness' or 'disingenuity' (or possibly something else)?

Tags: word-choice

Someone who is disingenuous is someone who displays ________ (fill in the blank). Is it 'disingenuousness' or 'disingenuity' or something else?

Comment: To be disingenuous is to lack sincerity, but someone who is disingenuous rarely intends their insincerity to be "on display."

Comment: I would say *disingenuousness* if I had to choose one of yours.  I'd prefer to say (like @LittleEva I think) something like "Someone who is disingenuous is someone who conceals their desire to deceive".

Answer (score 2):

The term is [disingenuousness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disingenuousness) :

Disingenuous:

> - Not straightforward or candid; insincere or calculating: "Increasingly, the question of immigration has become a disingenuous stalking-horse for race and racial hostility" (Tyler Stovall).
> - Pretending to be unaware or unsophisticated; faux-naïf.

Usage Note:

> - Disingenuous usually means "insincere" and often seems to be a synonym of cynical or calculating. Not surprisingly, the word is used often in political contexts, as in *"It is both insensitive and disingenuous for the White House to describe its aid package and the proposal to eliminate the federal payment as "tough love."*

The Free Dictionary

[Disingenuity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuity) is a less common synonym as shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disingenuity%2Cdisingenuousness&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisingenuity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisingenuousness%3B%2Cc0) (disingenuousness vs disingenuity)

(M-W)

Comment: "disingenuity", I love that word - really.